# is there a hook that is run before a window is deleted

Tags: window, hooks

I want to do some custom stuff before a window is deleted?

`window-configuration-change-hook` seems to be invoked **after** a window is deleted.

Comment: One idea would be to run a `pre-command-hook` and/or a `post-command-hook` with a test for a list of functions that would trigger additional *custom stuff*:  `(when (memq this-command '(.....)) custom-stuff)`.  If the condition is not met, there is virtually zero overhead.  And, these hooks can be buffer local if so desired.  The test can be more complicated of so desired, e.g., a particular major-mode, current window of the previous command is the same window as the new command, etc.  I *cannot* recommend advising `delete-window` or `delete-other-windows` as they are too fundamental to mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspection of `delete-window` in `GNU Emacs 25.1.50.2 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2016-04-25` shows that there is no such hook.

I don't right follow the argument of [lawlist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2287/lawlist) in his [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37874/is-there-a-hook-that-is-run-before-a-window-is-deleted#comment59641_37874) that `delete-window` is too fundamental to be advised.

For an example the following advice would provide a hook for functions with a `WINDOW` argument that is run before window `WINDOW` is deleted.

```el
(defvar window-before-delete-functions nil
  "Functions to be run with argument WINDOW before \(delete-window WINDOW).")

(defun delete-window-ad (window)
  "Add `window-before-delete-functions' as before-advice of \(delete-window WINDOW)."
  (run-hook-with-args 'window-before-delete-functions (or window (selected-window))))

(advice-add #'delete-window :before #'delete-window-ad)
```

Just remove the hook functions in `window-before-delete-functions` if something goes wrong with them.